# Cancel subscription within sink in SwiftUI Combine

Tags: swiftui, combine

Is there a way to cancel a subscription within a sink? Below seems to work but comes an error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your subscription must be global, otherwise it will disappear immediately.

```
class MySecondClass {
    ...
    var myGlobalSubscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    func subscribe() {
        myGlobalSubscription = myPublisher
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
                ...
                self?.myGlobalSubscription?.cancel()
            })
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `.drop()` or `.prefix()` functions of your publisher to skip certain number of upstream values. Or you can use a `.filter()` function to filter the upstream values.